# c++ killing specified thread in running process

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process, kill

Well. I have no idea how to kill specified thread in a running process since I'm not well experienced with coding. For example

We've got several threads in skype.exe

http://gyazo.com/e88c4ec35f00cf138b7bdfee5cd968bb.png

So yeah, any example how to kill skype.exe+0x70cc (it's example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717.aspx) -- but be aware that it's quite dangerous, and should almost always be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: yea but any way to kill the thread by his Start Address instead of getting his threadid? It would be great if you could make some example for me.

Comment: @user2808312: Not directly, no. You can enumerate threads in the target process, then use [`NtQueryInformationThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx) with `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress` to get the start address of each though.